# Mocking a method from from testing class not working

Tags: junit4, easymock, powermock

Lets say following is the class that I need to test

```
public class ClassToTest{
//some code
    SomeOtherClass soc = new SomeOtherClass();
    Object returnedObject = soc.doMethodCall(passedObject);
}
```

I don't want to let the actual doMethodCall happen and I need to mock it and return value of my own.

In mytest class I add preprare for test for SomeOtherClass

```
@PrepareForTest({ SomeOtherClass.class})
```

I did the mocking as follows.

```
SomeOtherClass mockSoc = EasyMock.createMock(SomeOtherClass.class);
Easymock.expect(mockSoc.doMethodCall((ParamClass)EasyMock.anyObject())).andReturn(null);
EasyMock.replayAll();
```

The problem is intercepting method call and return null instead of the method call doesn't happen and unit test go into doMetodCall(Which I don't want) and produce a null pointer error.

What I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

My original answer to this question is correct, but really specific as to why. After having done some more reading and using of PowerMock, I've run into this issue myself a few times. The issue you're facing is because the class that needs to be prepared for test is the class you're testing, not the class that you're mocking the construction of.

So to fix your issue, change `@PrepareForTest({ SomeOtherClass.class})` to `@PrepareForTest({ ClassToTest.class})`

***END EDIT***

---

I've been reading up on PowerMock recently and came across this page: [How to mock object instantiation with PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

I've tested your scenario creating a couple of classes myself. So here are the test classes I created to test your scenario:

```
public class Class2 {
    public Object doMethodCall(final Object passedObject) {
        return passedObject.toString();
    }
}

public class Class1 {
    public Object method(final Object passedObject) {
        final Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        return class2.doMethodCall(passedObject);
    }
}
```

Using the advice on that page, I created the following test method which runs successfully and tests that the method has been called on the new instance.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Class1.class)
public class Class1Test {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        final Object passedObject = new Object();
        final Class2 mockClass2 = PowerMock.createMock(Class2.class);

        PowerMock.expectNew(Class2.class).andReturn(mockClass2);
        EasyMock.expect(mockClass2.doMethodCall(passedObject)).andReturn("YEAH!");

        PowerMock.replay(mockClass2, Class2.class);

        final Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        final Object returnedValue = class1.method(passedObject);
        Assert.assertEquals(returnedValue.toString(), "YEAH!");

        PowerMock.verify(mockClass2, Class2.class);
    }
}
```